# Full screen video problems

Tags: html, css, video

The video seems to work perfectly fine fullscreen. The only problem is that i can't see my headers. It seems that the video is overtaking them. I just want to see the headers when i scroll down apart from the video.

Does anyone know the solution?

```css
    * {
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    body {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
    
    header {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        background: transparent;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    
    video {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        -o-object-fit: cover;
        object-fit: cover;
    }
```

```html
<body>


    <header>




        <video poster="messi.jpg" autoplay="true" loop>
            <!-- <source src="ships.mp4" type="video/mp4"> -->
            <source src="https://player.vimeo.com/external/158148793.hd.mp4?s=8e8741dbee251d5c35a759718d4b0976fbf38b6f&profile_id=119&oauth2_token_id=57447761" type="video/mp4">
        </video>


    </header>

    <h1>test</h1>
    <h1>test</h1>
    <h1>test</h1>
    <h1>test</h1>




</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've used `position:absolute` for both header and video and `height:100vh` for video. That part is creating problem. Change height to 100% and position:relative.

```css
* {
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    body {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
      overflow-x:hidden;
    }
    
    header {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        background: transparent;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    
    video {
        position: relative;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        -o-object-fit: cover;
        object-fit: cover;
    }
```

```html
<body>


    <header>




        <video poster="messi.jpg" autoplay="true" loop>
            <!-- <source src="ships.mp4" type="video/mp4"> -->
            <source src="https://player.vimeo.com/external/158148793.hd.mp4?s=8e8741dbee251d5c35a759718d4b0976fbf38b6f&profile_id=119&oauth2_token_id=57447761" type="video/mp4">
        </video>


    </header>

    <h1>test</h1>
    <h1>test</h1>
    <h1>test</h1>
    <h1>test</h1>




</body>
```

Comment: It works but when make my browser smaller..the video isn't fullscreen anymore

Comment: What is happening when you change the window size?

Comment: the video becomes smaller and doesn't fit fullscreen anymore

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of your problem.

Comment: i can't share the screenshot :s Just copy the code in another code editor please to see what's wrong.